# Do comments get deleted automatically once the number of comments reaches a limit?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that all previous comments under a question that I asked [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26959/natural-origins-or-learned-habit-why-do-students-skip-concepts-before-applicati) disappeared. I was wondering if once the number of comments reaches a certain limit, they get deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those comments were not useful additions to your question and were deleted.

Here's what comments are meant to be used for:

- Request clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
- Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Comment: See https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment:  "Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer."

Comment: On StackOverflow, when the number of comments exceeds a certain limit, they get moved to a chat. Are you saying that this feature does not exist on the Math Educator's forum?

Comment: @Dominique The same systems that exist on SO also exist on Math Ed SE.  If a comment thread reaches a certain length, a flag is automatically raised, alerting moderators that a comment thread has gotten long.  Moderators then have the option to (a) move the comments to chat, (b) delete the comments, (c) do some combination of the above, or (d) do nothing.  Additionally, if a comment thread starts to get back-and-forthy, the users engaged in the back-and-forth will be invited to move their comments to chat.  In this case, the selected course of action was to delete the comments.